# Anyone here successfully used edmodo/cropper in their Project?

Tags: android, github, import

I'm trying to use the (apparently widely used) edmodo/cropper library in my Project but so far no tutorial could help me get it running.

This is how my Android Project structure looks right now:
[image]

Looks to me as if I imported it correctly. I can build both my App and the CropperSample Project.
But when I try to use the CropImageView in my app, it says "Class not found".

Their official wiki and how-to looks like an easy 2 step process, but it obviously isn't that easy if you don't know what you're doing.

EDIT: I'm trying to use the CropImageView in my app like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".image_cropper">



<com.edmodo.cropper.CropImageView
    android:id="@+id/CropImageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

It cuts off the closing tag for LinearLayout here, but you get the idea.

Comment: can you post the part where you are trying to use CropImageView?

Comment: I edited my question accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add `include 'cropper'` in your settings.gradle. or just add cropper as a dependency in your build.gradle `compile 'com.edmodo:cropper:1.0.1'`

Comment: I already included 'cropper' in the settings.gradle, but I forgot to add the compile line in build.gradle. It works now, thanks!

Comment: @PectoralisMajor it should be one or the other so you can remove the cropper and CropperSamples modules from your project